# The displayed font is weird in Ubuntu 18.04 when browsing source code on github

Tags: ubuntu, browser, fonts

I am using 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with GNOME 3.28.2. When I browse source code on github, the font is not fix sized like 'monospace' or 'ubuntu mono', I have tried different browsers, both chrome and firefox, but neither work. I have also tried to change browser's font setting, and used gnome-tweaks to change font, but none of them work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original "Language" setting is not "English (United States)", after I change the setting to "English (United States)", the font looks correct now.